# Would I get the [Pending Writes to SF] data or can solve problem on Heroku?

Tags: heroku-connect

Thanks for showing this question! I hope all of you keep healthy. Happy New Year!

Currently, our team has stored data in the Legacy system on Heroku and integrated it to enable interaction between the Legacy system and Salesforce data through Heroku connectors.

I have observed that when data is modified in the Legacy system, it is also modified in Salesforce through the Heroku connector. When the volume of data is low, data synchronization occurs smoothly at regular intervals. However, as the volume of data increases, synchronization-related errors start to occur, causing bottlenecks.

I'm unsure about how to handle the pending writes to Salesforce data from Heroku. I'm also uncertain if I can use PG Admin to delete the pending data in the Case table.

My question is below :

1. How to delete data directly from Pending Writes to SF.
2. A way to improve performance.

[image: Pending Writes to SF]

Could anyone provide assistance in resolving the above-mentioned issue?

If you have any additional advice, please let me know.